# coffeescript: loop through objects in array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, coffeescript

I am fairly new to coffeescript and am trying to loop through objects in an array but can't get it working correctly.

```
var val = [
    {id: 1, Text: "first" },
    {id: 2, Text: "Second" },
    {id: 3, Text: "Third" }
]
var idObj = 1

for idObj in val 
    console.log('this is' + idObj)
```

From the code above, I am trying to find the object where `id` is 1, but it returns true for all of them.
I have seen examples how to loop through arrays but not sure how it works for objects within arrays

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a few errors in your code

Firstly, you cannot use the `var` keyword in coffeescript

Next, you reuse the variable `idObj` in the loop and outside it, so it is shadowed inside your loop and not usable

And there seems to be a mismatch between your code and your output, as nowhere are you returning a boolean value.

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do:

```
val = [
  {id: 1, Text: "first" },
  {id: 1, Text: "first" },
  {id: 2, Text: "Second" },
 {id: 3, Text: "Third" }
]

targetId = 1

for obj in val
  if obj.id is targetId
    targetObj = obj

console.log(targetObj)
```

I renamed `idObj` to `targetId` which holds the id of the object you are trying to find

The loop iterates over an array of objects, so each item is the object.
I check if the id of the object matches what you are searching for, and if it does, I assign it to targetObj so you can use it after the loop

Alternatively you can do it as a one-liner using some of the [comprehension filters](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) available:

```
targetObj = (obj for obj in val when obj.id is 1)[0]
```